# Twitter Bootstrap with Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like integrate Twitter Bootstrap with an existing Spring MVC Project. Search returns abstract results with no tutorials or articles that outlines how to integrate the UI focused Bootstrap with Spring MVC.

What are the the steps in terms of configuration involved to integrate the frameworks?

Thanks

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap is a framework for CSS elements, and also some popup and HTML tricks. You can simply put your bootstap.css, jquery.js and bootstrap.js into your existing Spring MVC JSP pages. There is no secret to using both together; it's quite simple.

You can take a look in those examples. They may be useful to you.

- Example 1 - priyatam's GitHub [Spring MVC bootstrap showcase](https://github.com/priyatam/springmvc-twitterbootstrap-showcase). This is a good one, a complete project and ready to run
- Example 2 - Duckranger's [Spring MVC and Twitter Bootstap](http://duckranger.com/2012/07/spring-mvc-and-twitter-bootstrap-customizing-the-input-fields/)

Remember that Spring MVC will provide to you all data (via JSON or Model attributes) to build yout HTML file. Bootstrap will only personalize the theme of your page and, sometimes, calling Spring MVC REST endpoints to get Ajax data.

Comment: When I try to Import the Example 1 project to my eclipse it says no project to select.

Comment: Are you using maven to import?

Comment: Yes I have maven plugin installed

Comment: I've downloaded the project today and import as existing maven project on eclipse. It work fine. Did you select `Import from existing maven project` option?

Comment: I imported it as maven project. Imported it to eclipse, when I run it as maven project i use "clean package cargo:run" in goals option but it gives me build error, what should I use to run it from eclipse thanks

Comment: You may use [webjars](http://www.webjars.org) instead of placing resources to webapp folder

Comment: Hey. I don't know After so many years I can ask for help, but the 2nd link does not lead to any showcase code. Any other link for the 2nd example? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

this is a good easy tutorial show you how you can integrate a bootstrap to an existing Spring MVC project

[Beautify your Java web application with Bootstrap](https://samerabdelkafi.wordpress.com/2014/09/17/bootstrap-3/)